# Spring elastic-search integration: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.put([Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, elasticsearch-6

I am upgrading elastic 2.x to 6.x. I have to update the spring data dependency as well to do the elastic upgrade. (Using elastic cloud managed service with x-pack-transport)

Here is my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This include elasticsearch dependency version 6.2.2.

I am getting following error while initialize the spring application.

Connection Code:

```
private Client getEsClient(String clusterIps, String clusterName) throws UnknownHostException
{

    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "5s")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
            .put("transport.tcp.compress", true)
            .put("cluster.name", "cluster-id")
            .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", true)
            .put("request.headers.X-Found-Cluster", "cluster-id")
            .put("xpack.security.user", "user:password")
            .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode", "none")
            .build();

    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings);

    client.addTransportAddress(
            new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("<cluster>.us-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io"), 9343));
    return client;
}
```

Here is the exception thrown while initializing the spring context:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.put([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/elasticsearch/common/settings/Settings$Builder;

at org.elasticsearch.xpack.notification.email.Account.(Account.java:71)

at org.elasticsearch.xpack.XPackPlugin.(XPackPlugin.java:192)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:556)

Please let me know if anyone encounter this problem before.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, I was using incompatible version of x-pack dependency which is 5.6.1, spring data 3.1.3.RELEASE uses 6.2.2 version of elastic driver so we should use compatible x-pack dependency and that is 6.2.2.

Here is the updated dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Documentation available here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-xpack-client.html